# Matching word with php

Tags: php, regex

After doing some research I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have a list of bad words and I want to be able to see if a user left a comment with any of those words. I have tried different regular expressions with no success. BTW Im no regex guru.

Lets say I have the word `$word = 'bi'` on my list. And a comment that says: `$comment = he is bi`, using `preg_match($pattern, $comment)` where parent has been: 1)`$word#i`

2)`/\s+($word)/\s+/i`

3)`/\b($word)/\b/i`

With this code:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $commentdata['comment_content'])) {
    echo 'spam';
 }
 else {
     echo 'true'
 }
```

I get:

1)`spam`this is also the case for words linke `combination` which I dont want to block

2)`true`

3)`true`

How can I make a pattern that only matches the word and not the word within?

Comment: `/\b($word)/\b/i` isn't even a valid regex. And what about word combinations such as 'bi-directional'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this do the job, you was near the solution:

```
preg_match("~\b$word\b~i", $comment);
```

For some particular cases like 'bi-directional' :

you can use instead:

```
preg_match("~(?<![a-z]-)\b$word\b(?!-[a-z])~i", $comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = "/\b{$word}/\b/i" ;
```

or

```
$pattern = "/(\b{$word}\b)/i" ;
```

Will do the work.